# Changes in CSS file do not appear in Sharepoint

Tags: css, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I'm a little bit frustrated of some Sharepoint troubles. I was able to apply custom CSS file in Sharepoint master page, but as I try to make some changes in this css file in Sharepoint Designer and I save it, these changes doesn't appear directly in Sharepoint online.

I absolutely don't understand, how is that possible, I didnt have any issue like this during uploading files via Sharepoint designer. Please, take a look to the pictures below. If any question, feel free to ask me, I spent a lot of time, but still unsuccesfull :(.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDhOz.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFlL0.png

Comment: Make sure the changes are published.

Comment: Well, thank you for your advice. I've just tried to reupload a new file from my local computer. If I reupload with the same name (or delete and upload new one with the same name), the custom css file content is the same of the first uploaded file with this name. If I upload another css (different name) file and apply this new file in master page settings, its working. It looks like some issue with cache, but I've never saw something like this, when I reupload the file, changes are not included in this file :X.